# Race condition when updating a field in Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thread-safety, race-condition, sidekiq

I have a concurrency of two threads in Sidekiq and at one point I call the following method in one of my models:

```
def update_pending
  update(pending_stats: self.pending_stats + 1)
end
```

I would expect that when both jobs finish, the pending_stats attribute is two, but it is just one, even though both threads call that method.

How can I make sure that the two threads update actually with the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [increment_counter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods/increment_counter) which is an atomic operation.

```
    def update_pending
      increment_counter(:pending_status, 1)
    end
```

This would execute following SQL:

```
    UPDATE ...
    SET pending_status = COALESCE(pending_status, 0) + 1
    WHERE ...
```

Comment: I see that when doing this, I need to reload the object? Otherwise even though in the DB the changes are performed, the object holds the old values. Why is that?

Comment: True, if we care about the new pending_status in the db after the update the object needs to be reloaded. Since it is a class method it does not know about object to reload.

Comment: I can do that, as I have the object. However, what is the impact of reloading the object?